# can't install html-agility-pack when install Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, json.net, html-agility-pack

I want to know why i can't install your pakage with Newtonsoft.Json and get this error :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' from source 'C:\Users\......\packages'.            0
```

I try to use from both of them in .net 4
And i try to install them from nuget package

anyway for install i can use from `ignore dependence` option  in `package manager > install and update option > dependence behavior` but sometimes when app is running and i got error...

any solution ?

[image: 2017-08-20_20h42_24]

Answer (score 0):

Delete **Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3** folder from c:\....\packages and remove it's line from packages.config then delete from project reference again install lower version.

Comment: i dont try this but i solve that problem with upgrade my nuget package manager... (maybe help to other...)